# Django model default value has a function after model creation and records insertion

Tags: django, django-models, default-value

Let's say I have a model called Marks, with the below fields

```
class Marks(models.Model):
    subject1 = models.DecimalField()
    subject2 = models.DecimalField()
    subject3 = models.DecimalField()
```

And I have added some records in this models,
Now I would like to add one more field which I missed, `total` so I have added it has `total = models.DecimalField()`

And to apply migrations, I need to provide some default value for the existing rows for this `total` field, but I don't want it to be static like `default=100` or something, I want it to be the addition of all three fields `subject1`, `subject2`, `subject3` and provide values in for the existing rows,

How can I do that, whether in migrations or using some functions.

Comment: If you want `total` to be the sum of other fields you don't have to add it as a column. You can always calculate it when needed. Otherwise see [data migrations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/migrations/#data-migrations).

Comment: hello @Selcuk this is just an example, but is there any way to actually do the calculations at the time of migrations and fill the existing rows?

Comment: Yes, there is a way. See the link in my comment above.

Comment: Thank you @Selcuk,  I have read the whole thing now on data migrations, I understand how it works, I will soon post my answer here.